# How would I style the text following a :checked radio button?

Tags: css, css-selectors, dynamic-css

I've tried the following:

```
:checked + *  
{  
font-weight: bold;  
}
```

With the following html:

```
<p><input type = "radio" name = "blah" />some text</p>
```

How would I go about styling such text?

**Solution:**

Throw label tags around the text, and select with
:selected + *

It works in opera and ff3, so I'm good.

Comment: You shouldn't combine the solution and the question. If you found your own solution, then post it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the label element to associate text and other inline content with form inputs:

```
<input id="foo" ...> <label for="foo" ...>foo text</label>
```

And then select with [for="foo"] or #foo + label or whatever.